# Processing a Table using Google Cloud DLP API is too slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

Recently, I have been trying to use the Google DLP API in Python 3 to classify the content of tables. I first started by testing the API on small examples, which all worked perfectly. However, as I attempted to send larger tables (1000 rows x 18 columns which is smaller than the 50 000 quota), the request would crash. 
After reducing the size of the table to 100 rows, I did manage to make it run, however a single request of 100 rows takes approximately 10 seconds. 
Most values are fairly short, you find some of the columns bellow:

- Address
- Date of birth
- Email
- First Name
- Gender
- Job Position
- Last Name

Furthermore, after further experimentation, I have noticed that if the same table is provided as a string in a CSV format (columns separated by "," and rows by "\n"), running time is reduced by a factor of 10.

Is this a normal behaviour? Or am I perhaps using the api poorly leading to such poor running performances?

I hope my question is clear enough,
Thanks for taking the time to read this ! :)

Comment: how do you send tables to dlp api?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue being worked on. Some detectors (DOB and name detectors) are working slower than desired on structured data.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the answer, How about the running as a string ? 
it's taking about a second for 100 lines (2962 tokens/words or 21101 characters), so something around 0.3 ms per token, is this a normal running time or is it slower than average ? 
Again, Sorry to bother you with these questions, thank you again for your time !

Comment: DOB, location and name detectors require complex algorithms that are currently on the slower side

Comment: Got it ! Thank you for your time, have a nice day

Comment: Just an update on this ... we made a change recently that increases the speed of this about 5x. The detectors as mentioned aboce will still be slower, but overall speed of table scans should be much improved.